# having trouble with excel formula using if isnumber or

Tags: excel-formula

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(AC4)=FALSE,AC4=0),"N/A",AX4/AC4)
```

this gives #VALUE AND YET:

- AC4 = 58
- AX4= 2227.83

iF I take out the AX4/AC4 and replace it with say 222 then the formula works as I put 0 into AC4 I get N/A and put back the 58 I get 222 in the BG4 cell that has the formula!

Its as if it doesn't like the AX4/AC4 !

Pete

Comment: are your sure the number in AX4 is a true number and not a string that looks like a number?

Comment: Good call, its a number but the value in AX4 is really 2227,83. It has a comma instead of a decimal. I f I change the comma to a decimal it works ok!

Comment: Now I just have to format the conversion from access to excel to use the decimal and not the comma. I believe the problem is with the computer the person is using is in French and using the wrong settings.

Comment: OR use this which will convert the `,` to `.`: `=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(AC4)=FALSE,AC4=0),"N/A",NUMBERVALUE(AX4,",")/AC4)`

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but this is how I have it working now. For some reason replace didn't work!

Comment: "=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(AC2)=FALSE,AC3=0),""N/A"",SUBSTITUTE(AX2,"","",""."")/AC2)"